# Agile Web Development with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have completed chapter 6 Task A: Product Maintenance but after completing the chapter am still not be able to see the pictures i have used while making product listing. It is just showing me only the name of that picture instead of real picture.

can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you show the code related to what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Male sure your images are in the correct directory, and double check the absolute/relative uri of the images you're calling. Double check with a static HTML page.

Comment: Thanks alot I hve resolved the problem I hadn't put the pictures in the appropriate directory.